# Javascript registers onmousedown event only when onmouseup happens? (They behave as the same event..)

Tags: javascript, events, onmousedown, onmouseup

I am testing a short script that is supposed to register whether the mouse button is held down, however on all the browsers that I tested it both onmouseup and onmousedown events fire simultaneously - when mouse button is unpressed.

This is one example:

```js
var check = 0;
document.onmousedown = function() {
  check++
}
document.onmouseup = function() {
  check--
}
setInterval(function() {
  if (check) {
    console.log(check)
  }
}, 1000 / 30);
```

Which is supposed to spam '1' in the console when the mouse is held down, however it does not work. And with this code:

```js
document.onmousedown = function() { 
  console.log('down');
}
document.onmouseup = function() {
  console.log('up');
}
```

It is easy to see that nothing fires when the mouse is pressed, but both events fire when the mouse is released. What am I missing?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you attach the event listeners to `document.body`?

Comment: I can't replicate what you've described. I've converted your code blocks to Stack Snippets ([details here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). When I run the first one, it does indeed spam 1 to the console while the mouse is held down. When I run the second one, I get `down` in the console when I press the mouse button, then later `up` when I release it. I've tested Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE11. What environment are you doing this in?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) and the snippets do not work as intended there.

Comment: I'm using that same Chrome version and it works as expected. Try disabling extensions to see if one of them is interfering.

Comment: Thanks! Disabling extensions fixed the error. Now to find which one was the problem..